# 12 V to 5 V reduction for bi-directional motor (DCC model train)

Tags: dc-motor, zener

I am modifying some old DC model trains to be DCC (digital control with a decoder). The decoder puts out 12 VDC PWM to the motor, but obviously switches the polarity around to change train direction.

I am replacing all my old DC trains' 'ringfield' motors with modern can motors e.g. CD motors, and in most cases have been able to find 12 V motors that are a simple like for like replacement electrically.

However, for some trains with six-wheeled bogies the 12 V motor is too big in depth (12 mm) to fit and I needed a smaller sized motor. I ended up finding a 9 mm motor but given it's designed for laptop CD drives it wants a lower voltage, 1.5-6 V, so I need to protect the motor by reducing the voltage.

The simplest way is adjusting the CVs of the decoder to set starting, mid speed and max voltages, however, not all train DCC decoders support these and mine currently do not, so I need a modification electronically.

Most people told me to put a resistor in series but that's not ideal as it affects the starting current of the motor and may prevent it from getting the train moving.

The solution I am looking at is two zener diodes back to back and so I created this:

[image: zener diode motor over-voltage protection]

I'm anticipating the above will shunt anything above 5 V in either polarity through the zeners and Rs (5 W resistor) will ensure it is not a short circuit.

Can anyone advise if this is going to work as expected or is it likely to blow up my decoder?

Answer (score 0):

First, I doubt that a 5 VDC motor suitable for model RR traction power would draw only 46 mA, although that might be possible with no load. I would expect it to be around 1 watt or even 5 watts, which would be 200 mA to 1 amp. So I found some data on an eBay listing:

https://www.ebay.com/itm/265386189878

It shows a stall current of 850 mA, so I would expect about 500 mA under full load. This is about 2.5 watts.

So to drop 12V to 5V, a resistor of about 14 ohms would work. It would dissipate about 3.5 watts. Under no load conditions, the zener diodes would need to consume about 2.5 watts for regulation. So you would need to find something like a 5W 5V zener.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvXO2L.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: Bipolar motor PWM]

If you have room, you might be able to use a PWM signal routed through two DPST relays which will activate on +12V and -12V, respectively, providing bipolar PWM to the motor. A simple square wave will provide about 6 VDC, and you can use a smaller duty cycle to adjust speed, although that may not be possible. The circuit above is conceptual, and may need some tweaking, depending on what you have available for the controller.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Let me see if I understand correctly - are you saying the circuit design is ok but the sizing of components is incorrect?  Regarding room there is not much inside a model train sadly.  I'm trying to keep the solution to a few small components on a piece of stripboard.  I get the feeling that it would be simpler to just buy better decoders and limit the maximum voltage.

Comment: Yes, the basic circuit is OK, but the motor will need a much lower series resistance to draw its rated current. I added another circuit but it's rather complex and klunky. So if you can get better controllers, or a suitably sized 12V motor, that's probably your best bet.